# Display the SQL definition of a hive view

Tags: hadoop, hive

How to display the view definition of a hive view in its SQL form.
Most relational databases supports commands like

`SHOW CREATE VIEW viewname;`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `show create table`.

Read the [hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowCreateTable) for more detail.

Answer (score 6):

It is DESCRIBE [EXTENDED|FORMATTED] also. show create table doesn't give enough information sometimes, but DESCRIBE always does;

> For a view, DESCRIBE EXTENDED or FORMATTED can be used to retrieve the view's definition. Two relevant attributes are provided: both the original view definition as specified by the user, and an expanded definition used internally by Hive.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-DescribeTable/View/Column

Comment: This command works even if you user does not have access to execute "show create table" command  +1.

Comment: This works for me. SHOW CREATE TABLE gives me only a part of the statement.

Answer (score 2):

SHOW CREATE table ;

Even thought its a view's definition that you'd like to get, the 'table' keyword has to be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, You can use SHOW CREATE TABLE to display the CREATE VIEW statement that created a view.

Link for reference: [Hive CREATE VIEW](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateView)